# Self-hosted OCR

Tags: ocr, text-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am looking for self-hosted OCR software.

Requirements:

- Optical character recognition on images
- Not just documents but also natural-scene-images
- Linux Support
- List item

Examples:

- https://ocr.space/
- Comparable to [Amazon's Rekognition](https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition/?), worse performance would be ok

I already tried [Tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) and [EAST](https://github.com/argman/EAST) + Tesseract but did not get satisfying results.